# What is the "dogfood" build?

Tags: naming-conventions

What `dogfood` build does mean? I mean, I know alpha versions, beta versions, but I never heard about `dogfood`. For which <strike>dogs</strike> people this build?

For example here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/u2020/blob/master/build.gradle#L29

Comment: See [Joel's explaination](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2004/04/16.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`dogfooding` is when a team working on a project brings that project home to use in their own everyday life, as a means of LIVE QA TESTING.

The developers get to see how the project runs from a QA point of view in the setting they are comfortable in.

This method of testing helps to catch many problems that otherwise may have taken much longer to find using standard quality assurance practices.

Some links with more info:

[wikipedia: Eating your own dog food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food)

[The Google Test and Development Environment - Pt. 2: Dogfooding and Office Software](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2014/01/the-google-test-and-development.html)

[Geosoft: How dogfooding has helped us improve quality assurance](http://blogs.geosoft.com/exploringwithdata/2010/12/how-dogfooding-has-helped-us-improve-quality-assurance.html)

Answer (score 7):

"Dogfood build" designates builds produced for internal use within the company, typically for finding bugs in new features that would be to embarrassing to show to an external customer.

The name comes from ["Eating your own dog food"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food) colloquialism, which refers to companies using their own products for its internal operations. The term is believed to have originated with Microsoft in the 1980s.

Comment: I'm pretty certain that phrase has been around longer than that but, being an old fart, my memory may be failing me :-)